# How do I find out word count in pages 5.2.2

Tags: pages

I often write short articles and am limited to 100 words per document.

Can I find word counts in pages 5.2.2?

Comment: Could you edit your post to let us know if you use Pages on iOS or OS X or the web interface?

Answer (score 8):

You can show the word count, character count, and number of paragraphs in a document.
Show word, character, and paragraph count

- Click [image] View in the toolbar, then choose Show Word Count.
- The word count appears at the bottom of the page.

  Move the pointer over the right side of the word count, then click the arrows to see character and paragraph count.

  You can choose one of these counts to display it (instead of word count) at the bottom of the page.

once word count in turned on, you can select a portion of text and it will automatically display the count for that selection.